# Performance aware solution for relevant sorted result of string search in large array of objects

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, filter, time-complexity

It's a simple and classic scenario:

I have a large array of around 80k object (NSManagedObject) let's suppose it's `Books` objects with `title` parameter as `String`. Users can search by `Book` title and I need to filter the large array and display the result in relevant sort order. We know that all titles are capitalized. A brute force algorithm should be (Code example can be tested in a Playground):

```
import Foundation

class User: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool { lhs.id == rhs.id }

    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String

    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}

let terms = Array(repeating: User(name: randomName), count: 80_000)

let query = "a"

let capitalizedQuery = query.capitalized

let start = Date()

let fullMatches = terms.filter { $0.id == capitalizedQuery }

let prefixMatches = terms.filter { 
    $0.id.hasPrefix(capitalizedQuery) && !fullMatches.contains($0) 
}

let containsMatches = terms.filter {
    $0.id.range(of: query, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil &&
    !prefixMatches.contains($0) && 
    !fullMatches.contains($0)
}

let result = fullMatches + 
prefixMatches.sorted { $0.name.count < $1.name.count } + 
containsMatches

print(Date().timeIntervalSince(start))

///

var randomName: String {
    String((0..<Int.random(in: 1..<30)).map { _ in
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".randomElement()!
    }).capitalized
}
```

The algorithm will display the full matches first the terms with prefix sorted by the closest to the full match (closer character count) and then any item that contains the query.

Example query: "Joh"

Result:

["Joh", // full match
 "John", // closest to the match 
 "Johny",
 "Johan",
 "Johanna",
 "Bonjoh", // just contains the query
 "Mojohfary"
]

The problem that this simple example takes around 5 seconds. The objects that I'm dealing with are a lot heavier. Is there a solution to optimize the performance of the relevant search.

The only optimisation that I see is to combine the first two filters and drop the last:

```
let result = terms.filter {
    $0.id.hasPrefix(capitalizedQuery)
}.sorted { $0.name.count < $1.name.count }
```

Now it's just 1s but now it shows only items with prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are `NSManagedObject`s I recommend doing the fetch and sort directly in your store. Having the `NSManagedObjectContext` handle the "filter" and sort will be more efficient.

Roughly:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Book")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(#keyPath(Book.title)) ==%@", title)
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: ascending, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
```

You will have to replace your logic in the request, predicate, and sort.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I come up to a conclusion that querying the store directly is not an option since the operation takes around 2 seconds (without sorting) and that's the maximuim that I can optimize there. Same operation in memory takes around 0.09 s but my question is how to optimize the result  of the in memory search

Comment: Which part takes 5 seconds?
`The problem that this simple example takes around 5 seconds`

Comment: One optimization I can see you doing is pulling out `!fullMatches.contains($0)` since that is repeated twice.
In even better optimization on `!fullMatches.contains($0)` would be if you could get the array of Books to be a dictionary. You'd no longer need to loop through all the entries in `fullMatches` you would be able to have a O(1) - constant time - to see if the title is there.

Comment: You could also do a `lazy` sort on `prefixMatches` when you first filter through them. This would save on time and memory.

`let prefixMatches = terms.filter { 
    $0.id.hasPrefix(capitalizedQuery) && !fullMatches.contains($0) 
}`

becomes

`let sortedPrefixMatches = terms.lazy.filter { 
    $0.id.hasPrefix(capitalizedQuery) && !fullMatches.contains($0) 
}.sorted { $0.name.count < $1.name.count } `